# VueJS push a route with params data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parameters, components

I am very new to VueJS.  How can I get the deviceId in Device component in vuejs.  The deviceId in h1 tag was not printed out in the Device component page.

```
    goForward() {
      console.log("go forward");
      this.$router.push({ name: "Device", params: { deviceId: "Air-conditioning" } });
    },
```

---

```
<template>
  <div class="about">
   <h1>This is the device page {{ deviceId }}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
   name: "Device",
   props: ["deviceId"],

 data() {
   return {};
  },
};
 </script>
```

---

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/device',
    name: 'Device',
    component: Device,
  },

]
```

Comment: Add your router config

Comment: @PierreSaid just added

Comment: How you the prop at the new page from prop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to receive your params as props you need to add the `props: true` option in the route object.

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/device",
    name: "Device",
    component: 'Device',
    props: true
  }
];
```

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that you can improve the URL scheme a bit by adding a route parameter like so:

```
{
  path: "/device/:deviceId",
  ...
}
```

Thus, the URL in the address bar will look cleaner:

```
https://www.example.com/device/Air-conditioning
```